# Why is subscribed event always null?

Tags: c#, events

I declare a subscription to event in:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public void btndel_bar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
        sc.FieldUpdate += new SomeClass.FieldUpdateHandler(sc_FieldUpdate);
    }

    void sc_FieldUpdate(object sender, ValueEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Smth_property);
    }
}
```

And here is I want to listen event:

```
public class Someclass
{
    public delegate void FieldUpdateHandler(object sender, ValueEventArgs e);
    public event FieldUpdateHandler FieldUpdate;

    void Somemethod()
    {
        string str = "Steel";
        ValueEventArgs args = new ValueEventArgs(str);
        FieldUpdate(this, args);   
    }
}
```

A class which carries data:

```
public class ValueEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private string smth;

    public ValueEventArgs(string smth)
    {
        this.smth = smth;
    }

    public string Smth_property
    {
        get { return smth; }
    }
}
```

I always have `FieldUpdate=null`. How to solve it?

Comment: if you declare `SomeClass` in `btnDelBar..` then its scope is within that method

Comment: It doesn't even compile...

Comment: You are subscribing to event from an object instantiated in the same method, an object that immediately goes out of scope.

Comment: Nikola Markovinovic where should I subscribe to this method?

Comment: It is not *where* but *to which object*. `sc` should probably be declared in class scope rather than in method scope. If you do it that way please do not forget to unsubscribe from previous instance of `sc` when you click on `btndel_bar` for second time. P.S. If you wish to contact someone please put `@` in front of his/her name so that that person gets notified.

Comment: It is still entirely possible that `Someclass` fires event before there is an handler attached. And of course the event might never be listened to. For this reason you should test for null before invoking event anyway. See [protected virtual void OnChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in first example of MSDN event tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read articles about delegates and events and after reading I always I thought to make all operations again. I did all over again and it works! Consequently I done something wrong when I did at the beginning of.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `Somemethod()` in the constructor, before the calling code gets a chance to add the event handler.
Therefore, the event is still null.

Comment: I've edited my conditions of subscribing. I subscriped in constructor just for example. Actually I do not subscribe in constructor. –

Answer (score 0):

The moment you create the object of `SomeClass` your event would get reinitialized.

Make your event a static so that multiple objects of SomeClass would share it

```
public static event FieldUpdateHandler FieldUpdate;
```

Comment: I have a code where my delegates and events are not static and it works perfectly. But in this case my event is null.

Comment: It made an error: it is not possible to get access to the member Somemetod.FieildUpdate by reference of an instance; specify name of type.